# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value - NestJs

Tags: javascript, jwt, nest

I get this error while implementing jwt in my server. I'm using NestJs and I'm following the documentation. I've been looking for solutions about this error here but it seems nothing works.
I've stored the secret key in my .env file, add ConfigModule.forRoot() in my app.module, so I can successfully read all my environment variables. This is my code, if someone can point me in the right direction.

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    PolsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController, AuthController, PolsController],
  providers: [UsersService, AuthService, PolsService, JwtService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '4h' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, UsersService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.controller.ts

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post()
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user.id };
    console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
    return {
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
}
```

console error

```
// console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
fb8C47vylwS
[Nest] 50225  - 01/07/2022, 17:46:37   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:107:20)
    at JwtService.sign (/Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/node_modules/@nestjs/jwt/dist/jwt.service.js:28:20)
    at AuthService.login (/Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/src/auth/auth.service.ts:26:37)
    at AuthController.login (/Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/src/auth/auth.controller.ts:29:29)
    at /Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at /Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /Users/user/dev/backend/pol-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

As I said I tried different potential solutions I found in other similar questions, (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673430/error-secretorprivatekey-must-have-a-value)) but none of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I'm late to the party, but I was just banging my head against this problem and just found a solution.

The problem is probably on this row in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [UsersService, AuthService, PolsService, JwtService],
```

JwtService should not be added as a provider. If you do, it seems to reset any registered options.

Comment: Same I was banging my head against the wall... thank you man.

Comment: totally helpfull, its the incorrect error for the registration of JwtService  as you said! thanks!

Comment: inside auth.model.ts we have providers, there just remove >> JwtService

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the `ConfigModule` in the `AppModule`, but not as a global module so your `AuthModule` does not know about it. That is why it does not know the secret.

You can either import the `ConfigModule` in the `AuthModule` as well or import it as a global module from within the `AppModule`.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in the `AuthModule` register the `JwtModule` asynchronously using `registerAsync`. Use a factory in which you inject the `ConfigService` exported from the `ConfigModule`.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET_KEY'),
          signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  ...
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

The `ConfigModule` as imported in the `AppModule` reads the `.env` file in an async I/O op. By registering the `JwtModule` asynchronously and injecting the `ConfigService` dependency you are making it wait until the `ConfigModule` has been loaded and the `.env` file has been read. Just use the `ConfigService` to read the environment variable and cast it.

More information about using the `ConfigService` can be found in NestJS's documentation.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice

Comment: I've done as you said but it still doesn't seem to work. I've managed to make it work by adding the private key directly in the sign method. It works but it doesn't seem right to me, I'd like to figure out why I cannot set the secret key in the module.

Comment: Did you put the `.env` file in the root of your repository and is the JWT secret put in there in the correct format? (`JWT_SECRET_KEY=value`). The `ConfigModule` should then read that file.

Comment: Yes I did, in fact all the others environment variables are read correctly. Only this one gives some problem. It works right now doing so

async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user.id };
    return {
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload, {
        privateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        expiresIn: '4h',
      }),
    };
  }

Comment: Passing in the secret to jwtService.sign(...) is possible, but is not necessary if setup correctly. By default the sign() method will use the secret setup when you imported the JwtModule. 
If you pass in a secret to the sign() method explicitly it will use that one instead, but it will always fallback to the one you passed when importing the module. See line 114 in the source code of jwt.service.ts from the @nest/jwt module: https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/09159fa69e6244b1f7ba09b51d9f7d7ad6f6e587/lib/jwt.service.ts#L114

Answer (score 3):

you can change

```
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY
```

to

```
secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `JwtService` and `AuthService` from the providers in app.module.ts. Also remove `AuthController` from the controllers in app.module.ts.

This worked for me when I had the same error message. Although I am not entirely sure yet why this works (I am very new to NestJS), here is my reasoning:

You pass the `AuthModule` (which already contains the `AuthController` and `AuthService`) to be imported in the `AppModule`. By adding `AuthController` and `AuthService` again at the root (`AppModule`) level, I believe you defeat the purpose of having the `AuthModule` in the first place and do not use the module context. By adding `JwtService` to the `AppModule` providers, you override the `JwtService` registered in the `AuthModule` context with an empty one.

Again, I am new to NestJS, so corrections are very welcome.

**Edit:**
I assume you were following the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication), which unfortunately does not show the AppModule.
They do however link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/19-auth-jwt/src/app.module.ts) where only the Module (not the Service) are imported:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, UsersModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Registering the module and controllers on the root AppModule is the correct way to get up and running with nest js routing: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#getting-up-and-running

Comment: i found helpful this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71287106/3281273

Comment: @PaoloFalomo this is true, but in the example all controllers are published via the AppModule. The OP publishes the AuthController in the AppModule and then again in the AuthModule (which is imported in the AppModule and will therefore be applied as well).
Importing the module and then again listing the providers and controllers kind of defeats the purpose of the modularity and can lead to problems as far as I can tell.